# Is this $V = R(T)\oplus N(T) \implies T^2 = T$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T$ is a linear operator on $V$, I know that if $T^2 = T$, then $V = R(T)\oplus N(T)$. But I'm struggling with the converse.

Comment: I guess V must be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's true just by considering $T(v) = 2v$ on say $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It's not forbidden to answer your own question, but if you do it after $5$ minutes it looks strange. If you just wanted confirmation that your answer was right, you should have put it in the question.

Comment: I actually thought about this for a while before posting my question. But few minutes after posting the question, the answer just occurred to me.